# How to create a menu in the administrative panel to manage content from a sidebar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

My goal: I would like to have a sidebar on my website with dynamic content manageable by an area in the administrative panel, as well as posts, pages.

My research points to creating widgets, but this section is in appearance> widgets

I think there must be some way to manage a widget in a new menu created in the administrative panel (in order to make life easier for my users without administrator permissions). Below is an image of where the new menu should be to manage the content of the widget

[image]

Comment: Have you already added your menu page in the admin or do you need to know the code for that too?

Comment: It really much depends on what type of content do you plan to put on the sidebar. If you want a list of something, then maybe you need to create a custom post type (which will then "automatically" have a menu item in the admin side panel; maybe it's something you can do with Advanced Custom Fields; maybe other...